# Faces of cones give localizations of affine toric varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

I'm trying to establish an explicit description of the open subsets of affine toric varieties given by faces of the underlying cone.

#### Background

For a rational convex polyhedral cone $\sigma\subseteq N_\mathbb R$ over a lattice $N$, we know that the semigroup algebra $S_\sigma=\sigma^\vee\cap M$, where $M$ is the dual lattice of $N$, is finitely generated by some $m_1,\dots,m_k\in M$, thus
$$
U_\sigma =\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[S_\sigma]) = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[\chi^{m_1},\dots,\chi^{m_k}])
$$
and we find an explicit (coordinate) description of this affine variety by looking at the $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism given by
\begin{align}
\varphi : \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_k] &\longrightarrow \mathbb C[\chi^{m_1},\dots,\chi^{m_k}], \\
x_i &\longmapsto \chi^{m_i}
\end{align}
And let $U_\sigma = \mathbf V(\ker \varphi) \subseteq \mathbb C^k$.

Now let $\tau = \sigma \cap H_m$ be the face given by some supporting hyperplane $H_m$ with $m\in S_\sigma$. From this description we have the dual $\tau^\vee = \operatorname{Cone}(\sigma^\vee \cup \{-m\})$ containing $\sigma^\vee$, then for the semigroups we have $S_\tau = S_\sigma + \mathbb Z(-m)$, so all that happened is we made one of the elements  of $S_\sigma$ invertible in $S_\tau$. Thus on the level of $\mathbb C$-algebras we have the localization
$$
\mathbb C[S_\tau] = \mathbb C[S_\sigma]_{\chi^m} = \mathbb C[\chi^{m_1},\dots,\chi^{m_k}, \chi^{-m}],
$$
where $m\in S_\sigma = \mathbb N\{m_1,\dots,m_k\}$.

#### Question

How can we relate $U_\tau$ in coordinates to $U_\sigma=\mathbf V(\ker \varphi)\subseteq \mathbb C^k$ as given above?

I guess we should look at the situation in $\mathbb C^{k+1}$ first, since we have $k+1$ generators now and project down to $\mathbb C^k$ afterwards, but I'm not sure how to do this.

#### My thoughts

Consider
\begin{align}
\psi : \mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_k,y] &\longrightarrow \mathbb C[\chi^{m_1},\dots,\chi^{m_k},\chi^{-m}], \\
x_i &\longmapsto \chi^{m_i},\\
y &\longmapsto \chi^{-m}.
\end{align}
By treating $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_k]$ as a subalgebra of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_k,y]$ we have $\ker \varphi\subseteq \ker\psi$. Since $m\in S_\sigma$, we have $m=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i m_i$ for some $c_i\in\mathbb N$. This relation yields
$$
\chi^m = (\chi^{m_1})^{c_1} \cdots (\chi^{m_k})^{c_k},
$$
so $x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_k^{c_k} y-1\in\ker\psi$ and thus
$$
\ker \psi \supseteq \ker\varphi + \langle x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_k^{c_k} y-1\rangle. \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
*Do we have equality here?*

Continuing this line of thought, we have
$$
U_\tau = \mathbf V(\ker \psi)\subseteq \mathbb C^{k+1}.
$$

The projection $\mathbb C^{k+1}\to\mathbb C^k$ that sets $y=0$ is injective on $U_\tau$: Every point $(x_1,\dots,x_k,y)\in U_\tau$ is a solution of $x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_k^{c_k} y=1$, thus $y=x_1^{-c_1}\cdots x_k^{-c_k}$ is uniquely determined. So we can identify $U_\tau$ with it's image in $\mathbb C^k$.

If we had equality in \eqref{1}, we could conclude
$$
U_\tau = \left\{\, (x_1,\dots,x_k)\in U_\sigma\,\big|\, x_1^{c_1}\cdots x_k^{c_k}\neq 0 \right\},
$$
which is an open subset of $U_\sigma$.

Is this reasoning correct and do we infact have equality in \eqref{1}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $f$ be a non-zero element.  Write $R_f$ for the localization of $R$ at $f$.  Then Spec($R_f$) is naturally contained in Spec($R$): it is the locus where $f$ is non-zero.  This is just the geometrical version of the commutative ring theory statement that the prime ideals of $R_f$ are the prime ideals of $R$ that don't contain $f$.

---

Edited to add: in response to the OP's first comment, let me try to say a bit more.

We do have equality in (1), because $R_f=R[y]/(fy-1)$.

Projection from Spec($R$) x $\mathbb C$ to Spec($R$) corresponds to the inclusion of rings of $R$ into $R[y]$.  To get the geometric map, we intersect prime ideals of $R[y]$ with $R$.  A prime ideal in $R[y]$ lying on the hypersurface defined by $fy-1=0$ restricts to a prime ideal in $R$ such that $f$ is non-zero.  In particular, this holds for maximal ideals, i.e., points.

Comment: I knew about that, but I'm trying to give the geometrical statement a precise coordinate-wise description.